# Why does comparing a varchar to a numerical value always return True?

Tags: mysql, varchar

I've got the following table in MySQL (MySQL Server 5.7):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SIMCards (
SIMCardID INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
ICCID VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
MSISDN BIGINT UNSIGNED UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO SIMCards (ICCID, MSISDN) VALUES
(89441000154687982548, 905511528749),
(89441000154687982549, 905511528744),
(89441000154687982547, 905511528745);
```

I then run the following query:

```
SELECT SIMCardID FROM SIMCards WHERE ICCID = 89441000154687982549;
```

However, rather than returning just the relevant row, it returns all of them. If I surround the ICCID in quotes, it works fine, e.g.:

```
SELECT SIMCardID FROM SIMCards WHERE ICCID = '89441000154687982549';
```

Why does the first SELECT query not work as I expected?

Comment: String compares are different from numeric compares. If you want it to be compared in one way or the other, you need to specifically type cast the values to either varchar or int or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integer in MySQL has a maximum value (unsigned) of `4294967295`.  Your IDs are substantially larger than that number.  As a result, if you select * from your database by integer, your behavior is going to be undefined because the number you are selecting by cannot be represented by an integer.

I'm not sure exactly why you are getting the results that you are getting, but I do know that trying to select by an integer when your data can't be represented by an integer will definitely not work.

Edit to add detail I forgot: even a bigint in MySQL is not large enough to represent your IDs.  So you need to make sure and just always use strings.